# Expected value of $E[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty} y \cdot \frac{y}{a^2} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2a^2}}dy$

Tags: integration, statistics

The following is the expected value for the rayleigh distribution:

$$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty} y \cdot \frac{y}{a^2} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2a^2}}dy$$

Now I can use the following substitution:
$u = \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}a}$

Substituting this back in the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} 2u^2e^{-u^2}du$$

However, the book shows me that I should get:

$$2\sqrt{2}a\int_{0}^{\infty} u^2e^{-u^2}du$$

Where does the $\sqrt{2a}$ come from?

Comment: You forgot about about the differential: $dy$ changes to $\sqrt{2}a du$.

Comment: Dimensional analysis would have provided a sanity check. Since $Y$ has the dimension of $a$, $E[Y]\propto a$.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply that
$$
\sqrt{2}a\; du=dy
$$